# How to get single value from Json file in bash?

Tags: shell, unix, grep

I would like to get a single value from output.txt file, and run different other bash commands based on the returned value pattern;

> cat output.txt `enter code here`

**SAMPLE FILE DATA**

```
{ "Topics": 
  [ 
    { "Name": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:freezing-deploy-topic"}, 
    { "Name": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:dense-deploy-topic" }, 
    { "Name": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789012:tenki-deploy-topic" } 
  ] 
}
```

**Shell script file**

```
while read line
do 
    if [[ $line =~ 'tenki-deploy' ]]
    then 
        echo "$line"
    fi
done
```

Comment: if you could use/install jq then jq is your tool here

Comment: `jq -r '.Topics[].Name | select(test("tenki-deploy"))'`

Comment: BTW, `while read line` should pretty much always be `while IFS= read -r line`. Without the `IFS=`, you trim trailing whitespace; without the `-r`, you munge literal backslashes in the data, or (if such backslashes are just before EOL) can have a `read` continue onto the following line of input.

Comment: how to use exceptions eg. it should through an error when it could not find "tenki-deploy" from json file. and I want to use them in a if/while statement loop